# hide/show multiple table rows by one anchor click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with several rows, I have row that has anchor element when clicking this anchor some rows that have display none should be shown.

**I need when clicking the anchor with class** *.pending-wide-col-name* **to toggle the class** *.dis-none* **on the table rows with class** *.results-secondary-hidden-row*

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="results-main-row has-hidden-row">
   <td>
    <a  class="pending-wide-col-name">some text</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="results-secondary-hidden-row dis-none">
   <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="results-secondary-hidden-row dis-none">
   <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="results-secondary-hidden-row dis-none">
   <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.dis-none {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is my javaScript code:

```
var mainRowWithHiddenChild = document.querySelector('.has-hidden-row .pending-wide-col-name');
var secondaryHiddenRow = document.querySelectorAll('.results-secondary-hidden-row');
mainRowWithHiddenChild.addEventListener('click', function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < mainRowWithHiddenChild.length; i++) {
    secondaryHiddenRow[i].classList.toggle('dis-none');
  }
});
```

**I tried this JS code but it is not working.**

Comment: replace `mainRowWithHiddenChild.length` with `secondaryHiddenRow.length`.

Comment: Why not add onclick a class to the table, something like `secondary-hidden` and in the css `.secondary-hidden .results-secondary-hidden-row { display : none }`. Then there is no need to select all the elements and change their classname individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `secondaryHiddenRow.length` in iteration instead of `mainRowWithHiddenChild.length`

```js
var mainRowWithHiddenChild = document.querySelector('.has-hidden-row .pending-wide-col-name');
var secondaryHiddenRow = document.querySelectorAll('.results-secondary-hidden-row');
mainRowWithHiddenChild.addEventListener('click', function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < secondaryHiddenRow.length; i++) {
    secondaryHiddenRow[i].classList.toggle('dis-none');
   }
});
```

```css
.dis-none {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="results-main-row has-hidden-row">
   <td>
    <a  class="pending-wide-col-name">some text</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="results-secondary-hidden-row dis-none">
   <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="results-secondary-hidden-row dis-none">
   <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="results-secondary-hidden-row dis-none">
   <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```